# On which Stack Exchange site should I ask about Adobe Dreamweaver hosting?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

The question:

> How does [Adobe Dreamweaver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Dreamweaver) website hosting/publishing work? Is it a local hosting type of service?

Which Stack Exchange site will be suitable for asking this question?

I searched for Adobe Dreamweaver in "search all sites" and found questions were asked on Stack Overflow, but they are mostly related to its programming angle.

Comment: is it about graphics

Comment: That question does not look like it's about graphics.

Comment: Depends on the question. The one you presented is... technically valid for SO? it's a "tool" used for "programming"? though i'd question why you'd want to ask that on SO rather than going to the first google result. I wouldn't expect it to be well received.